# Multiply columns with rows by matching column name and row name in Python / Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame which looks like this

```
> data
  A B
1 1 2
2 2 1
```

I have a reference data frame which looks like this

```
> ref
  Names Values
1     A      5
2     B     10
```

I want to multiply each column by corresponding row in Ref having same Name

the result should be this

```
> result
   A  B
1  5 20
2 10 10
```

What is the fastest way to achieve this in Python? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to check `mul`

```
df.mul(ref.set_index('Names').Values)
Out[137]: 
    A   B
1   5  20
2  10  10
```

Comment: `data.mul(dict(ref.values))` You can multiply by a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just what I was after

Answer (score 1):

Your reference dataframe `ref` can be represented as a `Series` as follows or with `ref.set_index('Names')['Values']`

```
s = pd.Series([5, 10], index=['A', 'B'])
```

Your `data` dataframe is as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1,2], B=[2,1]))
```

Multiplying the two with `df * s` produces the desired output because the indexing of each object is used to determine which arrays get multiplied together.